# Why does my function return undefined when trying to return the max number from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

My function returns undefined rather than 3, I'm aware I can use:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

However, I want to first try and see if I can do so without utilizing a native function since I'm trying to improve my skills as a dev.

```
var my_max = function(arr){
var max=arr[0];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] > max) {
        max=arr[i];
    }
}
return max;
};

console.log(my_max(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no array there. You're just passing three numbers to the function. You should instead pass an array of three numbers:

```
console.log(my_max([1, 2, 3]));
```

---

Alternatively, you can use rest parameters in your function, like that:

```
var my_max = function(...arr){
  // ...
}
```

Then you can call it without using an array:

```
console.log(my_max(1, 2, 3));
```

Comment: Important to point out that rest arguments are an ES2015 feature and so only some browsers support them today.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By `some browsers` you mean IE, right?

Comment: @Gothdo: Even Firefox and Chrome only started supporting them relatively recently. Edge supports them, IE11 doesn't, Safari doesn't.

Comment: Chrome 47, FF 15, Opera 34 support them.

Comment: If you are OK with rest operator why not do this like `var myMax = Math.max(...[1,2,3]);`